# Kafka: explicitly assign a non-zero initial offset at topic creation

Tags: apache-kafka

When creating a new kafka-topic, is there any way to set the minimum offset for all its partitions to a value larger than 0? If there is no direct way, is there probably an indirect way by directly manipulating the kafka-internal offsets?

Asked differently, how could a function `createTopic("foo", 4, 1000)` be implemented that creates a new topic of name "foo", consisting of 4 partitions, where the first produced message per partition will get offset 1000 (rather than 0), the second 1001, and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there is no way for doing that but the question is what are you trying to achieve with that ?
I'm guessing that you are trying to use the offset as a sort of unique identifier for your messages, is it ? Why don't use the key for that ?

Comment: Indeed, I would like to use the offset for a monotonously increasing numeric message-id (particularly in single-partition case). This allows efficient progress-monitoring downstream. AFAIK, assigning keys to messages would require to provide an id/key on my own (e.g., via zookeeper), which is implementation overhead. The reason for creating a topic with custom offset is that in case of an eclatant failure (which might force to delete the topic) one could simply recreate the 
topic, starting at a high-enough offset in order to continue processing safely without re-assigning earlier used ids.